# Insert by joining two tables

Tags: mysql

I've tables `all_usernames` which has columns `srno` and `username`. `username` is unique and `srno` is auto-incremented.

There is another table `blockers` that has columns `srno_blocker` and `srno_blocked`. It stores `srno` of users (`srno_blocker`) who blocks another users (`srno_blocked`).

**Question:**
I've `srno` of blocker and `username` of user to be blocked. I need to write query to insert record in `blockers` accordingly.

For that, one query to get `srno` of `username` (user to be blocked) and then another query to insert record in `blockers` is one solution. But it needs to fire two queries.

How this can be done most efficiently (in a single query using joins)?

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: As I mentioned currently there is two queries I am firing but its not efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO blockers (srno_blocker, srno_blocked)
  SELECT <blocker_srno>, u.srno
  FROM all_usernames As u WHERE username = <blocker_username>
```

of course proper parametrization depending on your language/sql lib

Comment: try updated code, i haven't db here, so fine tune it yourself. But definitely you can use INSERT using SELECT form